# How to lerp in JavaScript without smoothing?

Tags: javascript

I am drawing shapes on a canvas every frame and I want to move a shape between 2 positions with a constant speed.

I am using a lerp function I found:

```
const lerp = (start: number, end: number, amt: number) =>
  (1 - amt) * start + amt * end;

const onFrame = () => {
  const newPositionY = lerp(currentPositionY, destinationY, 0.01);
  // use new position to move shape
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
```

However this causes my animation to "smooth" because the closer it gets to the destination the "slower" it moves to it (because of the speed aspect).

**How can I change this to be a constant speed?**

In Unity I would multiply my speed by `Time.deltaTime` but when I reproduce that in JavaScript by tracking delta time as a variable my shape "jumps" pretty much immediately to the destination:

```
const lerp = (start: number, end: number, amt: number) =>
  (1 - amt) * start + amt * end;

let deltaTime
let lastFrameTimestamp

const onFrame = () => {
  deltaTime = (Date.now() - lastFrameTimestamp) / 1000;
  lastFrameTimestamp = Date.now();

  const newPositionY = lerp(currentPositionY, destinationY, 0.01 * deltaTime);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
```